# 2020 Moderator Election - Results

Tags: discussion, election

History's [first moderator election](https://history.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the four new moderators are:

[image: Mark C. Wallace] [image: Robert Columbia] [image: Semaphore] [image: T.E.D.]

They'll be your elected moderators going forward, and will show up in [the existing crew](https://history.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly— please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5650248362885120/0).

Answer (score 8):

Congratulations all around to the elected moderatos; and a hearty thank you also to everyone who, elected or not, by putting their name forward volunteered for this often thankless role.

The site continues only because these individuals volunteer their efforts.

Answer (score 7):

Thank you! I am humbled by your support!